# I can't delete the right item in a ListView with custom adapter by clicking imageButtom

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

### When i click on the imageButtom in the listView it always removes the first item. I need to delete the item that its imageButtom has been clicked.

PedidoLista.class

```
public class PedidoLista extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<Movimiento> productos;

public PedidoLista(Context context, List<Movimiento> productos) {
    this.productos = productos;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return productos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return productos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return (long) Integer.parseInt(productos.get(position).getIdref());
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, 
    final ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_lista, null);
        holder.txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista1);
        holder.txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista2);
        holder.txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista3);
        holder.ib4 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.lista4);
        holder.ib4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                productos.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    Movimiento papa = this.productos.get(position);
    holder.txt1.setText(papa.getNombrepale());
    holder.txt2.setText(papa.getDescripLarga());
    holder.txt3.setText(papa.getCant());
    return view;
}
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt1;
    TextView txt2;
    TextView txt3;
    ImageButton ib4;
}
}
```

pedido_lista.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/asd"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lista1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="4"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lista2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="35"
        android:text="123456789123456789123456789123456789"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lista3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/lista4"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/kkkrojo"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I need help with this!

Comment: Set the click listener outside the `convertView == null` if

Comment: @PedroOliveira even out of the else, just before `return view;` right? cuz if  its NOT null, then the old onClickListener will be active which holds a wrong position. right?

Comment: Yes. Listeners should be set like the text or whatever you're doing with your holder.

Comment: Keep position in ViewHolder and take it after clicked. And I suppose that you should use RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the code below. But I suppose that you should use `RecyclerView`. There is it already implemented.

```
public class PedidoLista extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Movimiento> productos;

    public PedidoLista(Context context, List<Movimiento> productos) {
        this.productos = productos;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return productos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return productos.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (long) Integer.parseInt(productos.get(position).getIdref());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, 
        final ViewGroup parent) {
        //you have to make your view holder as final
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pedido_lista, null);
            holder.txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista1);
            holder.txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista2);
            holder.txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista3);
            holder.ib4 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.lista4);
            holder.ib4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   //here you get current position from view holder
                    productos.remove(holder.position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        Movimiento papa = this.productos.get(position);
        //here you set current position
        holder.position = position;
        holder.txt1.setText(papa.getNombrepale());
        holder.txt2.setText(papa.getDescripLarga());
        holder.txt3.setText(papa.getCant());
        return view;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt1;
        TextView txt2;
        TextView txt3;
        ImageButton ib4;
        int position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code below should set outside the if-else:

```
    holder.txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista1);
    holder.txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista2);
    holder.txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista3);
    holder.ib4 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.lista4);
    holder.ib4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            productos.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: setting OnClickListener every time when you get view is not good solution

Comment: Setting onClick everytime is the best solution since view will get recycled and you need to pass a final field to it @KonradKrakowiak. But since this was already answer on the comments I see no point on posting this answer here.

Comment: I cannot agree with you @Pedro Oliveira. I think that you can set OnClickListener for every view on time when then were created, and use ViewHolder to keep current position

Comment: You can get the view passed to the onClick listener and get it's parent or parent of parent depending on your layout, get it's tag, convert it to viewholder and get it's position on the adapter.

Comment: Yes but you onClick has view which was clicked as parameter, so you have to call set parameter on Image button. Look on my solution above (first comment). What do you think about it? I get position from viewholder and I set and keep current position in viewholder too.

Comment: My solution looks better than set new OnClickListener every time when getView method is called. And it works

Comment: Yes I can see that working. Still better to use RecyclerView since it has `ViewHolder.getPosition()` already implemented. :)

Comment: That's right I wrote it in my post, but if some one want to use ListView it is his decision.